# Physically opening a notepad with java

Tags: java

All I was able to find while searching through previously asked questions was how to open/write/read from a text file.

I was wondering how I would go about physically opening a text file (as if I opened it myself). Is there some command for this, and if so, can it be applied to other programs? ex: paint, calculator, microsoft word, ect...

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't you be much better off writing a simple Windows batch script, or bash if on linux, etc.? That isn't Java's purpose.

Comment: To physically open a notepad, you'd have to build a robot arm to do so for you...

Comment: @CorayThan it is just a small part of a much larger java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends...

Do you want to open a file in a platform independent manner so it opens the default editor associated to the file as specified by the OS or not...

If you do, then you should take a look at [`Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)

For example...

```
File file = ...;
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

or

```
Desktop.getDesktop().edit(file);
```

Now, remember, this will open the associated program for the give action and is specific to the user's context, that is, I have NotePad++ setup to edit *.txt files, so on my system using this method will open NotePad++, on other systems it may open NotePad or what ever the user has configured for that file

Take a look at [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");`

For more details check:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get the program you want to execute as a file Object, e.g:

`File f = new File("C:\\test\\test.exe");`

Then execute it using

`Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");
process.waitFor();
```